# Search multiline text in a file using powershell

Tags: powershell

I am not an expert at PowerShell.  I am trying to search for a multi-line string in a file, but I don't get the desired result.

Here is my code:

```
$search_string = @("This is the first line`nThis is the second line`nThis is the third line")
$file_path = "log.txt"
$ret_string = @(Get-Content -Path $file_path | Where-Object{$_.Contains($search_string)}).Count
Write-Host $ret_string
```

`$ret_string` is set to `0` although `"log.txt"` contains exactly the same content as `$search_string`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few problems here:

1. You are searching an array of lines, not a string containing line breaks
2. If you're using Windows you need to use `\r\n` as a new line
3. The `.Contains` function will return a boolean value, so won't help you retrieve a count
4. Your `$search_string` does not need to be an array

You can use the `-Raw` parameter to get the entire file contents as a string. You're also better off using a regular expression to search here. Try:

```
$search_string = "This is the first line`r`nThis is the second line`r`nThis is the third line"
$file_path = "log.txt"
$ret_string = (Get-Content -raw -Path $file_path | Select-String $search_string -AllMatches | % { $_.matches}).count
```

This will return a count of all the occurrences of `$search_string` in the file

Answer (score 4):

`Get-Content` returns an array of strings (one per line), each of which is checked separately in your `Where-Object` condition. You need to read the file as a single string for your check to work:

```
Get-Content $file_path | Out-String | Where-Object { ... }
```

On PowerShell v3 or newer the cmdlet has a parameter for reading the raw file:

```
Get-Content $file_path -Raw | Where-Object { ... }
```

Note, however, that you may need to adjust your condition to check for `` `r`n `` rather than just `` `n ``, particularly with the first approach.