# Powershell regex replace unescaped double quote followed by line break

Tags: regex, powershell, csv

I am processing a large csv file with fields enclosed in double quotes which has text descriptions containing unescaped double quotes which I need to replace with an escaped double quote. I have tried using the following regex: `(?<!^|",)("(?:$[^"])|"(?!,"|$))` which is able to find the unescaped quotes except when they are followed by a line break. Any help in resolving this issue gratefully received.

I know the csv is incorrectly formatted but don't have control of this unfortunately, so I need to be able to correct the formatting for further processing.

Example:

```
"Field 1","Field 2","Field 3 "with unescaped quote"
followed by line break","Field 4"
```

Needs to become:

```
"Field 1","Field 2","Field 3 ""with unescaped quote""
followed by line break","Field 4"
```

Powershell script I'm using is as follows:

```
    [string]$path = 'C:\ ...'
    [string]$directory = [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($Path);
    [string]$strippedFileName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($Path);
    [string]$extension = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($Path);
    [string]$newFileName = $strippedFileName + [DateTime]::Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss") + $extension;
    [string]$newFilePath = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($directory, $newFileName);

    $reader = New-Object 'System.IO.StreamReader'($path, $true);
    $regex = [regex] '(?<!^|",)("(?:$[^"])|"(?!,"|$))'
    $writer = [System.IO.StreamWriter] $newFilePath;  

    try{
        while (($line = $reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null ){
            $newline = $line -replace $regex, '""';
            $writer.WriteLine($newline);            
        }
    }
    finally{
        $reader.Close();
        $writer.Close();
    }
```

Comment: How do you read your file? Are you using [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content)?, see: [Search multiline text in a file using powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51061537/1701026)

Comment: Besides, I think you need to redefine your definition as `...break","Field 4"` also contains an "*unescaped double quote followed by a line break*". Meaning that you might have to fix this by counting fields instead or look for *lines that do not start with a double quote*.

Comment: How do you _create_ your file? Described format _contradicts_ the following rule: [Fields that contain double quote characters must be surrounded by double-quotes, and the embedded double-quotes must each be represented by a pair of consecutive double quotes](http://www.creativyst.com/Doc/Articles/CSV/CSV01.htm#FileFormat).

Answer (score 1):

Next time, try to build an [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (also for yourself) as it might help to better understand the problem.
A common pitfall in this is the fact that the standard cmdlet [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) reads a stream of lines (`string[]`) where each line doesn't contain any line break itself but line breaks are used as a default delimiter (between each item in the array) when output to the display or a file. You might workaround this by using the `-Raw` parameter but that will read everything into memory and probably make it even more complex than it actually is.
I suspect that you actually want to look for *lines that do not start with a double quote* which means that the previous `csv` line is probably truncated. meaning, in such a case, you want concatenate the previous line with an extra double quote, reinsert the line break and add the current line:

```
Get-Content .\Input.csv | Foreach-Object { $Previous = $Null } {
    if ($_.StartsWith('"')) { 
        $Previous
        $Previous = $_
    } else {
        $Previous += '"' + [Environment]::NewLine + $_
    }
} { $Previous } | Set-Content .\Output.csv
```